# div.appendChild().appendChild()

Tags: javascript, appendchild

Logically, I want to embed an image in a link in a div.  I've successfully done this with either the link or the image.  I've even done it with the link and image in parallel (which is useless) for my purposes.  But can't seem to have the image wrapped in a link inside a div.

```
var div = OpenLayers.Util.createDiv();
var img = OpenLayers.Util.createImage(null, null, null, null, null, null, null, delayDisplay);
img.className = "olAlphaImg";
img.alt = altText;

var link = document.createElement("a");
// link.setAttribute("href", "#");
link.href="#" + altText;
link.appendChild(img);

div.appendChild(link); 

OpenLayers.Util.modifyAlphaImageDiv(div, id, px, sz, imgURL, position, border, sizing, opacity, altText);

return div;
```

This is for an OpenLayers where I'm trying to ensure keyboard navigation. I just am not sure how to do this with javascript and all the examples only use one appendChild reference.  I've tried with innerHTML() but I wasn't using strings so that didn't seem useful.

Comment: can you setup jsfiddle for this

Comment: True..  I will try to do that next time.  Oleg's answer below answered my question, but would have been better if I'd just done what you'd suggested first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What do you mean by

> can't seem to have the image wrapped in a link inside a div

Do you experience any errors?

I might have misunderstood your question, but if not, your code should work.

Here's my example: a **[working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A4Wmn/)** that wraps an image into a link into some container.

```
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = 'https://www.google.fr/images/srpr/logo3w.png';

var anchor = document.createElement('a');
anchor.href = 'http://google.com';

// Wrap image in the link (anchor):
anchor.appendChild(img);
// Insert the anchor into container:
document.getElementById('container').appendChild(anchor);
```

Comment: Thanks Oleg. This definitely helped.  I've played with it a bit here.  I was bundling it in OpenLayers and wasn't getting errors.  Pulling it out into a jsFiddle helped!  http://jsfiddle.net/mgifford/9jbc7/9/